# How to get option value index dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a list of select. I want to find an index when the option is selected. The option value taken from Database, but the index didn't refresh. This is my code

```
function loadListPenyakit(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://10.0.2.2.com/compfest/ajax/belajar/list_p.php',
            success: function(response){
                var file = '';
                $.each(response, function(index, item){
                    file += '<option value='+$("select[name='select-choice-b'] option:selected").index()+'>' + item.penyakit + '</option>';
                });
                $('#select-choice-b').html(file).selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Communication Server Error ');
            }
        });
    }
```

When i get the data from database, the Index value is 0. it mean that didn't refresh.
Help me please !

Comment: why are you setting the value of every option to selected index? can u clarify more? that way we'd be able to provide an alternate solution.

Comment: well, the problem is when i select the option, the index is zero for all option. i want to get the option index based on the option selected. then send the index into database for other process based on the index. so the index so important for the next process.

Comment: $(this).on("change", "select", function () {} didn't work on Jquery 1.6.4. i have change with $('#select-choice-b').live('change', function() {}, now is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use index that way. You'd have to get to index in the change event and send it to ajax call. With what you're having right now, you're setting the option value to something which doesn't exist. [**Here's a demo for what you're looking for.**](http://jsfiddle.net/pgYFx/4/)

#### And here's the JS :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#first", function () {
    //  $.ajax({
    //        type: 'get',
    //      url: 'http://10.0.2.2.com/compfest/ajax/belajar/list_p.php',
    //   success: function(response){

    //assume i got this from an ajax call
    var response = [{
        "penyakit": "tempor"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "consequat"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "non"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "esse"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "magna"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "laboris"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "cupidatat"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "eiusmod"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "nostrud"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "quis"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "ullamco"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "in"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "esse"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "ullamco"
    }, {
        "penyakit": "non"
    }]

    var file = '';
    $.each(response, function (index, item) {
        //dont use index now. it can be collected only during runtime ie., only when the dropdown changes
        file += '<option>' + item.penyakit + '</option>';
    });
    $('#select-choice-b').html(file).selectmenu().selectmenu('refresh', true);

    //  },
    //  error: function (e) {
    //    alert('Communication Server Error ');
    //  }
    //});


    //index must be taken in the change event
    $(this).on("change", "select", function () {
        var index = $(":selected", this).index();
        //use index variable to make ajax call now. 
        alert(index);
    });

});
```

Comment: Hey! I miss you on JQM.